# How to write rspec tests for ruby Script that works with Git

Tags: ruby, git, unit-testing, rspec

I have a Ruby Script that checks for changes between a git repo and files at url endpoints. If changes exist, it commits them and pushes them to the repo. I'd like to write rspec tests for this script, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do so, since I don't want the tests to actually push anything to an actual Git repo. I'm thinking I need to set up some sort of mock repository but I'm not entirely sure. Any suggestions for how to best write unit tests for such a script would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your code interact with the Git repository? Are you using a gem, or executing `git` commands with e.g. `exec("git ...")`?

Comment: The script uses ruby-git gem: https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can make use of the fact that it's perfectly legal to push to a local "bare" repository, i.e. you will need the following steps:

1. Create a "bare" repository `repo1` (i.e. a repository, that doesn't have a working copy, it consists entirely of contents of `.git` folder)
2. Clone regular repository `repo2` from `repo1`.
3. Make any changes as you usually do in `repo2` (add, commit, push). Check that push is successful.
4. Check that data is available in `repo1` too.

Here's a sample console session in my `/tmp` directory:

```
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp ♥ mkdir repo1
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp ♥ cd repo1 
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo1 ♥ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/repo1/
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo1 ♥ cd ..
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp ♥ git clone repo1 repo2
Cloning into 'repo2'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp ♥ cd repo2 
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ git remote -v
origin  /tmp/repo1 (fetch)
origin  /tmp/repo1 (push)
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ cd ..
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp ♥ cd -
/tmp/repo2
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ echo 'ohai!' >> readme.txt
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ git add readme.txt 
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ git commit
[master (root-commit) 1f1fb96] First commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 readme.txt
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 227 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /tmp/repo1
 * [new branch]      master -> master
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ git log
commit 1f1fb96deaaf15fa33f1682d87d85014b59b36db
Author: Alexey Shein <alexey.shein.dev@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 01:22:12 2015 +0500

    First commit
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo2 on master ♥ cd ..
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp ♥ cd repo1 
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo1 ♥ ls
HEAD  config  description  hooks  info  objects  refs
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo1 ♥ git log
commit 1f1fb96deaaf15fa33f1682d87d85014b59b36db
Author: Alexey Shein <alexey.shein.dev@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 01:22:12 2015 +0500

    First commit
ruby-2.2.0 in /tmp/repo1 ♥
```